# Why http.HandlerFunc always returns the same random number

Tags: go, gorilla

Greeting from newbie gopher!

I've got the following mux router setup:

`s.router.HandleFunc("/test", s.TestHandler())`

s.TestHandler:

```
func (s *server) TestHandler() http.HandlerFunc {
    rnd := rand.Intn(100)
    response := struct {
        RND int `json:"rnd"`
    }{
        rnd,
    }
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        s.respond(w, r, 200, response)
        return
    }
}
```

Helper method s.respond:

```
func (s *server) respond(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, code int, data interface{}) {
    w.WriteHeader(code)
    if data != nil {
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(data)
    }
}
```

The issue is when I issue GET /test, I see the same number unless app is restarted.

I'm certain I'm doing something wrong, would appreciate if someone please point out my fault.

Comment: Formally: Because you do not generate a "random" number, you generate a "pseud-random" number. This generation of numbers is deterministic, only the _sequence_ of numbers looks (a bit) random.

Comment: @Volker - that's true, but in the OP's question, it is because their handlerfunc does not include a call to `rand.Intn`, it includes the already-generated number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Function literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals)

> Function literals are *closures*: they may refer to variables defined in
>   a surrounding function. Those variables are then shared between the
>   surrounding function and the function literal, and they survive as
>   long as they are accessible.

---

`TestHandler()` generates a *single* random value and then returns a *function literal*, i.e. a closure, that uses this *already* generated value to send a response whenever it is executed by the router.

*But*, the surrounding function of a closure will not be, and has no reason to be, executed together with the closure whenever the closure is invoked. The surrounding function is executed only when it itself is invoked, like when you're registering the handler in `s.router.HandleFunc("/test", s.TestHandler())` for example.

So, in the provided code, the `rand.Intn` function in your `TestHandler` is called exactly once, it is not called, as you seem to believe, every time you hit the server with a request.

To fix this just move the random-value-generating code a level below:

```
func (s *server) TestHandler() http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        rnd := rand.Intn(100)
        response := struct {
            RND int `json:"rnd"`
        }{
            rnd,
        }

        s.respond(w, r, 200, response)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! I have to additionally learn when use and when not to use closure (use case is not 100% clear for me at the moment =)

Comment: @MichaelC Yes, in this case there's no real benefit of having `TestHandler` return a handler over having `TestHandler` just *be* the handler. There are, however, cases where you might actually *want* to do XYZ *only* once, and then, have the returned closure, re-use the result of that XYZ.

Comment: @MichaelC Consider this [example](https://play.golang.com/p/C_wMuD8DbMX), here you see that the parsing of the template is done only once and then the template is being reused by the returned closure, this saves a lot of cpu cycles that would otherwise be unnecessarily wasted if the parsing stage was inside the closure.

Comment: @MichaelC a lot of Go handler specific "middleware" is also implemented using closures, if you keep programming web servers in Go you'll encounter those soon enough. Also the following link may help shed some more light on how/when to use them: https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/#tmp_12

Comment: yes, I'm going to keep programming web apps in go, I like it much more than PHP I've been occasionally dealing with. Thank you for pointing me to right direction, I see closures can be potentially used in web apps to implement some middleware things...